# Monitor user's CPU usage

Tags: 16.04, server, users, cpu

I would like to run a script on 3 servers running Ubuntu 16.04 Server which logs each user's CPU usage. This can be a very "rough" log e.g. executing once an hour, checking how many cores are used by which user and outputting to .txt or .csv.

I could later post-process these logs with python to get my final result which should look like this:

- User: A; Total CPU-hours: 500 (300 on Machine A, 200 on Machine B, 0
  on Machine C)
- User: B; Total CPU-hours: 800 (300 on Machine A, 200 on    Machine B,
  300 on Machine C)
  ...

Can anyone give me a hint on how to get the servers to log the required Data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what details you exactly want to collect, however in similar situations I would suggest using `sysstat`.

```
sudo apt-get install sysstat
```

then you can use `sar` command to see what's going on. it also installs a `cron` script: `/etc/cron.d/sysstat` and saves data at `/var/log/sarX`.

You can use `sar -q` to get a report of load avg or `-P` for per-processor statistics, etc.

Example:

```
01:36:25 PM       CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
01:36:26 PM         1      8.08      0.00      2.02      1.01      0.00     88.89
```

Read more: [examples, outputs, ...](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/)